# assigning input values to cmdmysql.Parameters.Add using arrays

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to insert the values into "cmdmysql.Parameters.Add" using values from array. But it generates an exception value is already defined. Following is my code:

```
cmdmysql.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
string cd = ab;
string[] words = ab.Split(' ');

foreach (string word in words)
{
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@_maxvalue", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[0];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_userid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[1];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_templateid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[2];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_resultid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[3];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_duration", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = words[4];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_mode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = words[5];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = words[6];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_description", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[7];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_id", MySqlDbType.Double).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
}
```

so for example if i try to insert value into @p_maxvalue using words[0] it generates an exception @p_maxvalue is already defined. 
Does anybody has idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on what version you are using of .NET I would change the Parameters.Add to Parameters.AddWithValue .Add has been deprecated

```
cmdmysql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_maxvalue", words[0]);
```

the the only thing that I don't see you handling is DBNULL.Value if you try to insert a null value.. check it out [Parameters.AddWithValue MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)

Comment: that's why you will still need to check for that just incase.. DBNULL is a value but if you are always certain that there will never be any null data values to Insert.. then don't worry about it.. but data is never static and is always subject to change even if you don't change it..

Answer (score 2):

Do not use loop.

```
if(words.Length==8)
{
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@_maxvalue", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[0];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_userid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[1];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_templateid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[2];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_resultid", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[3];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_duration", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = words[4];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_mode", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = words[5];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_status", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = words[6];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_description", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = words[7];
    cmdmysql.Parameters.Add("@p_id", MySqlDbType.Double).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the foreach loop. A command can only contain a single value for a given parameter name, however when there is more than one word in the words collection, the specified code will attempt to use the same parameter name twice.

Comment: its working now... thnx... there is one more concern regarding typecasting of "@_maxvalue", MySqlDbType.Double).Value which is double value. I am type casting, but it doesn't allow me to put null where as in the table the same field maxvalue is nullable.